# Misalignment of cell background/borders in different browsers

Tags: css, xhtml

I have developed a nice table frame with css and graphics.  It uses background-image slices for a 3D heading and simple css borders for the rows.

The problem is that I need to align the borders with the headings and it simply won't work consistently in different browsers although I can't see why not.

In IE6 and IE7 it works OK

In IE8 and FF3.5 the left edge is out by one pixel

In Chrome 10 the right edge is out by one pixel

It seems the background image is not being placed fully to the edge of the heading cells, but it's hard to know even which browser to blame.  Any suggestions appreciated.

A live demo of the problem is at:
http://www.songtricks.com/TableBug.html

The HTML/CSS source is below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>    
    <style type="text/css">

    table.demo 
    {
      margin:0px;
      padding:0px;
      border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    table.demo tr
    {
      padding:0px;
      border:none 0px transparent;
    }

    table.demo th
    {
      border:none 0px transparent;
      border-bottom:solid 1px #cccccc;      
      padding:10px;
      background:url(wfx_table_tm.gif) repeat-x left top;
    }
    table.demo th.left
    {
      padding:0px;
      background:url(wfx_table_tl.gif) no-repeat left top;
    }
    table.demo th.right
    {
      padding:0;
      background:url(wfx_table_tr.gif) no-repeat right top;
    }

    table.demo td
    {
      border:none 0px transparent;
      border-right:solid 1px #dfdfdf;
      border-bottom:solid 1px #cccccc;
      padding:8px;
    }
    table.demo td.left
    {
      border-left:solid 1px #b1b1b1;  
    }
    table.demo td.right
    {
      border-right:solid 1px #b1b1b1;  
    }

    </style>    
    </head>

    <body>
        <table class="demo">
            <tr>
                <th class="left">Left</th>
                <th>Center</th>
                <th class="right">Right</th>
            </tr><tr>
                <td class="left">Left</td>
                <td>Center</td>         
                <td class="right">Right</td>
            </tr>
        </table>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `border-spacing:0` instead of `border-collapse:collapse` at the `table.demo` level.

If it breaks ie6/7 then you can include the border-collapse in a conditional CSS reference.

Comment: Musaul, sensational thanks! That did the trick, I wasn't aware of border-spacing before. What a great trick. I have added ie6/7 conditional overrides with the techniques below, do you think that is the best way? Thanks again! /* IE6 hack */ * html table.demo { border-collapse:collapse; } /* IE7 hack */ *:first-child+html table.demo { border-collapse:collapse; }

Comment: I wouldn't worry about "best" with the IE6 and IE7 hacks. If they work then call it done and move on to something more fun and interesting. Just make the CSS selectors as specific as possible to isolate the kludges.

Comment: I agree with *mu* as in if a hack for any version of ie works, then call it done. Except if you're going to have large chunks of CSS that you can't isolate using browser quirks, you can put them in a separate file and include it using [if IE] commented sections as described in http://www.gkspk.com/view/programming/minimum-and-maximum-widths-in-ie6/  (disclaimer: shamless plug to my site.) :p

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're using a background image to simulate the `border-right` for `th.right`. The background image goes **inside** the border area whereas the `<td>` immediately below it has a real border of 1px; the browser is making the `<th>` and the `<td>` the same inner width to line up the columns but the `<td>` appears 1px wider because it has a real `border-right` of 1px. Your `border-collapse: collapse` is hiding the width issue in the other cells.

The solution is to use your background image as a background image and a border for the border. Or, use the background image trick to put right and left borders on the `<td>` elements.

Comment: Thanks, your rationale is interesting, but how does it explain that it only happens on one side? Or that Chrome/Firefox/IE all behave differently with it? I have tried to use the background image trick on the td cells with a 1px wide image, but struck two problems that are even worse. (1) I sometimes need to merge all cells in a row with colspan and you can't have left/right background images at once on the single cell (2) In IE7 using a td background image hides the background color of the tr element which I'm using for alternating shading (not shown in my example above).

Comment: The `border-collapse` is hiding the issue on one side, add a `1px solid transparent` border to the `<th>` elements and you'll see the issue on the right side too. Different browsers render things differently all the time: browser bugs, ambiguities in the standards, differing interpretations of the standards, etc. Styling a `<tr>` is risky at best, IE generally ignores CSS on `<tr>` and often `<tbody>` (depending on version and the phase of the moon of course). Nesting `display:block` elements inside your `<td>` elements can help with your "single cell" issue.

Comment: I have noticed that IE7 in particular behaves badly with <tr> styling.  Anyway thanks the discussion, I seem to be up and running on my problem now with border-spacing.